# insertar variable javascript en una sesion php

Tags: javascript, php

```js
function bimestre(event) {
        var targe = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var o = targe.getAttribute('value')
        o = parseInt(o);
        console.log(typeof(o));
        // alert(event.target.innerHTML);
        var bimestre = "<?php  $bim =(int) "<script> document.writeln(o); </script>";  Session::set("bolo", $bim); ?>";
        return o;
    }
```

necesito insertar la variable valor en una variable de sesion php, porfavor ayuda

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo confusa. JavaScript es un lenguaje de programación del lado del cliente y PHP es del lado del servidor. Para comunicarlos necesitas un medio pero podrias enviar y recibir datos desde JavaScript a PHP mediante AJAX o JQuery.

Comment: Gracias lo hice por cokies, nose si es la mejor opcion pero funciono. Gracias por comentar. Me ayudó mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No puedes**.
Al menos directamente no. Esto debido a que ambos lenguajes tienen propositos diferentes. Javascript opera en el lado de cliente, y PHP en el servidor, si estas iniciando como programador esto puede resultar confuso, pero luego lo comprenderas mejor. Sin embargo puedes hacer hacer algunos truquillos para lograr lo que quieres.
Javascript se la lleva muy bien con el DOM, asi que puedes modificar con Javascript componentes del mismo y tomar su valor con PHP.Un mejor enfoque es usar Ajax para comunicar el cliente con el servidor y el amigo @guzgarcia te ha dado una buena respuesta. Si no quieres usar AJAX puedes usar el propio DOM:

*documento.php*

```
 <div ID="1">
  ...Contenido...
</div>
```

*php*

```
<?php
 $searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "div" )->getAttribute('Valor'); ?>
```

*Javascript*

```
 var node = document.getElementsByClassName('div')[0];
 //Por aca 'insertas' con javascript contenido que es tomado por PHP directamente del DOM
 node.setAttribute('Valor', 'TuValor');
```

Comment: What? Qué es `$xmlDoc`? y cuándo se supone que el servidor va a leer el valor del DOM? Y cómo? Qué sabe PHP del DOM?

Answer (score 1):

> necesito insertar la variable valor en una variable de sesion php

Para comunicar backend con frontend necesitas hacerlo vía peticiones HTTP. Si tu intención es enviar una variable que tienes en JavaScript al backend (PHP), solo necesitas hacer una simple petición.

El siguiente ejemplo envía `o` mediante ajax:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'server.php');
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      // se ha enviado la variable
    }
  }
xhr.send('bim='+o);
```

En `server.php` (o como se llame tu archivo php), obtienes este valor y lo añades a la sesión:

```
if(isset($_POST['bim']) {
  $bim = (int) $_POST['bim'];
  $_SESSION['bolo'][$bim];
}
```

Por supuesto que puedes hacerlo mediante una petición GET normal:

```
var o = parseInt(targe.getAttribute('value'));
window.location = '/server.php?bim=' + o;
```

Y obtienes `bim` por medio de `$_GET`:

```
if(isset($_GET['bim']) {
  $bim = (int) $_GET['bim'];
  $_SESSION['bolo'][$bim];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día

Esta es la línea:

```
    var bimestre = "<?php  $bim =(int) "<script> document.writeln(o); </script>";  Session::set("bolo", $bim); ?>"
```

En mi humilde opinión, se puede hacer que una variable php "imprima" por decirlo de alguna forma, algún contenido en las declaraciones js, pero en sentido inverso, que es lo que parece que quieres lograr, no funciona así

la instrucción document.writeln(), imprime valores en el browser, no en el script de php, eso sería inseguro.

visualiza como están organizados los elementos, browser, servidor, comunicación http entre ellos, y a esta disposición de elementos que interactúan, la puedes llamar "arquitectura", y en el modelo arquitectónico, te fijarás, que no hay posibilidad de que el browser, defina las instrucciones declaradas en el servidor en forma natural.

imagina, si yo pudiera alterar el código de javascript en el servidor de forma tan simple, y con eso empezar a ejecutar código a diestra y siniestra, sin una forma de autorización o punto de entrada, podría disponer de el servidor a mi antojo

ténicamente se puede hacer, pero no es el enfoque de esta tecnología